# Python "if" evaluates both hand sides of "and"?

Tags: python

Can anybody tell me why the following fails:

```
teststr = "foo"
if not teststr.isdigit() and int(teststr) != 1:
   pass
```

with:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```

In C if the first part in an `&&` test fails the right hand side is not evaluated anymore. Is this different in Python?

EDIT: I am being stupid. The `and` should be an `or` of course.....

Comment: maybe the `not` is causing the first part to evaluate to true?

Comment: @JohnBoker if I parenthese it, it still fails: `if ( not teststr.isdigit() ) and ( int(teststr) != 1 ):`

Comment: @RickyA: umm, those parens do what it's already doing.

Comment: @RickyA  (not teststr.isdigit()) is true

Comment: you probably want something like `if not (teststr.isdigit() and int(teststr) != 1)`

Comment: Crap. Sorry guys, my fault. Logic problem :) Those antibiotics must be messing with my brains.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`not teststr.isdigit()` is True, so the first test doesn't fail.

Comment: Yes, and that exactly where my brains stopped working...

Answer (score 2):

```
if not teststr.isdigit() and int(teststr) != 1:
```

is evaluated as

```
if ((not teststr.isdigit()) and (int(teststr) != 1)):
```

well, but `teststr` is not a digit, so `isdigit()` is false, so `(not isdigit())` is true. And for `True and B`, you have to eval B. That's why it tries the cast to int.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want

Comment: I can assure you that's not what you want, since if `not teststr.isdigit()` is true, the `int()` will raise an exception every time. Maybe you mean `or`?

Comment: well, but teststr is not a digit, so isdigit() is false, so (not  isdigit()) is true. And for True and B, you have to eval B.

Comment: @RickyA:  So you *want* to cast to integer when the `teststr` is not a digit?  Surely you are asking for an error.

Answer (score 0):

`if not teststr.isdigit()` is True, so then it needs to evaluate `int(teststr)` to complete the requirements of the `and` - hence the exception.

Instead of pre-checking data, utilise EAFP - and use something like the following...

```
try:
    val = int(teststr)
    if val != 1:
        raise ValueError("wasn't equal to 1")
except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
    pass # wasn't the right format, or not equal to one - so handle
# carry on here...
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you probably want to use would probably be

```
try:
    int(teststr)
except ValueError:
    print "Not numeric!"
```

It's generally more pythonic to try something and catch exceptions rather than use type-checking methods like you did.